# How can I force a text wrapping in a WPF TextBlock

Tags: wpf, textblock

I use a TextBlock as such:

```
<TextBlock Text="HelloWorld" Width="600" />
```

How can I have my text to render on two lines:

```
Hello
World
```

Can I use a special line wrap character, like the following?

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello\nWorld" Width="600" />
```

I do not want to change the width of the TextBlock because I do not want to use automatic text wrapping algorithm like TextWrapping="Wrap" or TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow": I want to be able to specify in the string itself where it should wrap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use LineBreak, it should do what you want.

```
<TextBlock>
    Hello<LineBreak/>World
</TextBlock>
```

You could also use 
 :

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello&#x0a;World" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You may set the TextBlock's [`Inlines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines.aspx) property, instead of `Text`:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Inlines>
        <Run Text="Hello"/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="World"/>
    </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```

which is the explicit form of what user *mcalex* has answered.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<TextBlock>
  First line
  <LineBreak />
  Second line
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: @ArnaudWeil I think you'll find Arhiman's answer is actually the same as mine, with an additional usage.